False Discovery Rate in continous and categorical exposure
Problem. 
I am performing linear regression models with 2 cognitive outcomes and 10 lifestyle exposures. Eight of the exposures are categorical, while the other two are continous, resulting in a total of 20 linear regressions (10 models for outcome 1 and 10 models for outcome 2).
Question.
A. When comparing my p-values with FDR q-values, should I conduct two sets of comparisons—applying FDR separately for continuous and categorical exposures?
B. Or should I apply FDR to all the variables together?
Thank you for your insights!

Building separate models for each of your predictors/exposures individually is not a good idea. It poses a big risk of omitted-variable bias. Multiple regression combining all predictors into a single model is better. That will give coefficients for each predictor when all others are held constant. Although one might argue for some type of FDR control on the set of coefficients, usually they are allowed to stand on their own with small models like this. One might also consider a single multivariate model for both cognitive outcomes.
